# Prepend meta_value to permalink of post

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, slug

I have 2 custom post types `movies` (non-hierarchical) and `series`(hierarchical). Each post from `series`type has a meta field `_movie` which contains a movie ID.

I want to specify a custom permalink structure for `series`. What I need to achieve is a link `http://example.com/series/movie_slug/parrent_series_slug/series_slug` (parent_series_slug is the slug of the parent of the series, they are hierarchical, if there isn't any parent, `parrent_series_slug` is omitted).

What I have achieved at the moment is `http://example.com/series/parrent_series_slug/series_slug`, which is handled by Wordpress. The question is how to insert `movie_slug` (slug of the post with the ID from meta `_movie`) in the permalink before series slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it seems like you'll want to hook into the WordPress rewrite rules.

[{$permastruct}_rewrite_rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/%24permastruct_rewrite_rules) doesn't have a lot of information, but this filter would allow you modify the array of existing rewrite rules to add in your new rewrite rule for series.

For this to work:

```
http://example.com/series/movie_slug/parrent_series_slug/series_slug
```

You'll need to add in movie_slug, parrent_series_slug, and series_slug as vars that WordPress will recognize with the query_vars filter.

[More information on WP_Rewrite with some examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)